# Find the cheapest combination of raw foods that fulfill nutritional requirements

Tags: algorithms, optimization, permutations

I am starting a raw food diet and would like to properly plan it, and thus, would like to create a program that takes a list of available raw food, and finds the best combination of foods (multiples allowed) with the lowest total price.

Does anyone have any advice as to how to approach this problem? Is there a certain algorithm that exists that takes in a list of possible items, and finds a permutation that minimizes one property of the item(s), in this case the price, and also makes sure that the sum of each property meets a certain range, in this case nutritional properties like carbs and protein? Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't try to delete your question by turning it into nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Use integer linear programming.  Suppose you have $n$ foods.  Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be zero-or-one variables, with the intention that $x_i=1$ means you include food $i$ in the combination.  Then the price is a linear function of these $x$'s, so that's your objective function you are minimizing.  If you want the total carbs to be within a range, you can express that as a linear inequality (e.g., $\ell \le c_1 x_1 + \dots + c_n x_n \le u$, where $\ell,u$ are the lower and upper bounds of the range and $c_i$ is the amount of carbs in food $i$).  Feed this to an off-the-shelf ILP solver, and it should give you the optimal answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking in Computer Science, I very much recommend George Dantzig's "Linear Programming and Extensions". It explains linear programming in a way that a normal human being (like me) can understand. The link has links to three .pdf files of this book.

https://www.rand.org/pubs/reports/R366.html

PS. D.W.'s recommendation to look at integer linear programming (instead of just linear programming) is important if you have food items that you can only buy in discrete sizes. For example, you can have an arbitrary amount of strawberry jam, but you must have no apples, 1 apple, two apple's, three apples, you can't have 1.7206 apples.

Solving the linear programming problem and then for example rounding the number of apples to 2 won't give optimal results. But you can take your equations, then once add a condition "apples <= 1" and then add a condition "apples >= 2". Solve both systems, and take the one that is better. This works well enough if you have only few items that are discrete.

Answer (score 0):

At the outset, I'll write this up in Java, or at least show my line of thinking from a Java standpoint.

Given that we're looking at Food items, we'll define a Food class that has:

A field/attribute for type of food (In our case, we'll take "raw" and "un-raw").
A field/attribute for the name of the food.
A field/attribute for the price of the food.

Note that I am not taking into consideration the actual caloric properties or anything health-associated for now. If I can come back to this answer later, I'll see if I have anything to offer on that front.

We'll define this class and then for our algorithm we'll take in as input a List, or informally speaking, a list of Objects that are all of type Food. We'll denote this as *List A.*

To solve the problem of minimizing price, we could use some sorting algorithm (quicksort, right?) on the item prices, and once we've sorted in ascending order, iterate through this list and add to a new List, denoted as *List B*, **only** those items which have the type "raw."

Your final *List B* would have only raw foods and those raw foods in ascending order of price.

### END OF INITIAL ANSWER

Now let's take a look at this caloric/health-property part of the problem. We'll say that you have three inputs for the algorithm:

1. *A List of Food items*
2. *A price bound, expressed as a double/decimal number*
3. *A calorie bound, expressed as a whole number*

We'll see that what you're doing is minimizing on two fronts instead of one. The first front we minimize on is price. What we'll do is we'll iterate through *List A* and add to *List B* only those items that are raw.

### SORTING ON PRICE, LIST B

We'll then sort through *List B* using price, so that we have raw foods arranged in ascending order of price. We'll take the sum of all the items' prices and see where we're at. Denote this as *initialTotal.*

If we're within the price bound, then we're good, and if we aren't... then there's problems. We may have to take out certain items based on price, but the interesting thing is that we'll have to also consider caloric intake there...

Let's assume you're within the price bound, so *initialTotal* <= *priceBound*.

### SORTING ON CALORIES, LIST B

We'll add up all the calories of all the items in *List B*, and denote this as *initialCal*.

If we're within the caloric bound, denoted as *calBound*, then *initialCal* <= *calBound*. If both conditions relating to total price and total cal hold, then we can return *List B* as it is.

Let us suggest the calories are off. What we can do is we can sort on the calories, and reorder *List B*. We could potentially reverse-sort on *List B* so we see the most caloric-heavy foods first, and the least caloric-heavy foods last.

We may be able to isolate some subset of *List B* as having the most caloric-heavy foods, say the *k* element subset of foods within *List B*.

We need to find the combination then of foods to get rid of such that *initialCal* <= *calBound*. Whatever remains, we can return.

I know this is a rather long answer, but hopefully in a few days I may be able to come and answer some more/significantly reformat the answer to be more helpful. My apologies for this being incomplete, as it were. I'll try to fix this soon.

Good luck with the diet!